# parallax background images zoomed in on mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm still pretty new to media queries so I'm not sure if i'm using them 100% correctly here. But for some reason, the home background image and the contact background image do not display properly in mobile view on my iPhone. I've searched many work arounds but still haven't found anything that works. My site link is - http://fharrishomecare.com  Any help will be greatly appreciated! Also when I hide the iframe map, it still leaves a block of blank space in tablet view. Any help with that would be appreciated too!

```css
#home {
  background: url('../images/colorful-bg.jpg') 50% 0 repeat-y fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact {
  background: url('../images/contact-bg.jpg') 50% 0 repeat-y fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

/* mobile responsive section styles
/* ========================================== */

@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 53px;
  }
  #counter .counter-item {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  #home,
  #divider,
  #contact {
      -moz-background-size: auto;
      -webkit-background-size: auto;
      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-position: top;
      background-size: auto;  
  }
 iframe {
    display: none;
 }
 
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  #home,
  #divider,
  #contact {
      -moz-background-size: auto;
      -webkit-background-size: auto;
      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-position: top;
      background-size: auto;  
  }
   iframe {
    display: none;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 38px;
  }
  #home h5 {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  #home .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 14px 32px;
  }
  #home,
  #divider,
  #contact {
      -moz-background-size: auto;
      -webkit-background-size: auto;
      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-position: top;
      background-size: auto;  
  }  
   iframe {
    display: none;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 34px;
  }
  #home h5 {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
  #home,
  #divider,
  #contact {
      -moz-background-size: auto;
      -webkit-background-size: auto;
      background-attachment: scroll;
      background-position: top;
      background-size: auto;  
  }
   iframe {
    display: none;
 }
}
```

Comment: `typeof properly == 'undefined'` in ***do not display properly*** expression.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Programming is exact, while `properly` is debatable (what i find proper you might find improper and vice-versa). Hence `properly`, `nice`, `beautiful`, `ugly`, `strange` and other such debatable terms should be avoided when describing a technical issue.

Comment: Um... Ok. Well, I stated the exact issue in the title. My fixed background images are zoomed in when displayed on a mobile browser. I apologize if the words I used weren't exact but that's my problem. Is this something you could help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your background images are not "zoomed-in" but, in effect, "not zoomed out". The backgrounds are displayed at their actual size on screens narrower than `1024px`.

This is caused by quite a few declarations in your `style.css` at lines `~480`, `~500`, `~525` and `~545` where a bunch of media queries repeatedly set the `background-size` property of `#home`, `#divider` and `#contact` elements to `auto`.

You should set the `background-size` property of those elements to `cover` if you want the background images to be as small as possible but still cover the element.

On the other hand, setting your `background-size` to `cover` would conflict with your chosen parallax method. Whenever you are vertically shifting the `background-position` via parallax on a `background-size:cover` element, the "block of white space" you describe appears. This could be fixed using two different methods:

1. Use of negative margins + paddings so the background is `zoomed-in` enough for the "white blocks" not to appear when the element is on screen
2. Use a different parallax method (absolutely positioned `<img>` tags or pseudo-elements that you could apply CSS transforms to).

Please note `style.css` currently has a considerable amount of sub-optimal code.
And your markup also has a few notable inconsistencies like, for example, some of your sections feature the `parallax-section` class while others the `paralla-section` which is nowhere to be found in your `CSS`.

Comment: Thanks! It's fixed and displaying as I want it to in mobile view. It did have something to do with the parallax-section inconsistency. I will fix that issue and remove the unnecessary code from the style sheet. Thanks again for your time and response!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad my answer was helpful in finding your solution. Please consider marking it as accepted.